# Loading xml file only once in list asp.net

Tags: c#, xml

I need to load XML file to List using following code

```
   public class MainClass {


    private class listClass {

        public string Name;

        public string property1;

        public string property2;


    }
    private const string XMLPath = @"";
    private List<listClass> List;

    public List<listClass> GetList() {

        if (List == null) {
            XDocument XML = XDocument.Load(XMLPath);
            List = (from _val in XML.Element("values").Elements("val")
                    select new listClass {
                        Name = _val.Element("Name= ").Value,
                        property1 = _val.Element("property1").Value,
                        property2 = _val.Element("property2").Value
                    }).ToList();

        }
        return List;
    }
}
```

I want to reuse this list again and again through out application without depending upon instance. XML file will be read only and only updated manually.

Should I make class and method static so that i need not to create object and load XML from file system to list again and again

Comment: Yes, the Singleton object is the best solution

Comment: should i keep it static or create singleton?

Comment: If you use a Singleton, you can do lazy loading, as is described here: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx (fourth or fifth version).